# Contar apenas de labels visiveis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

estou com uma dificuldade em meu código. Tenho um menu dropdopwn que exibe notificações. Quando a notificação mostra a mesma data do dia atual ele exibe  `<div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>`. O ícone de notificação tem uma badge que faz a contagem de `<div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>`, porém eu queria que somente fizesse a contagem quando elas estivessem visiveis, mas faz a contagem mesmo das divs ocultas. Tem alguma forma que posso fazer de contar apenas as divs com as labels "novo" visiveis de acordo com a data?

```js
//Função para atualizar as mensagens
function refreshItens(){


  setTimeout(function(){ 

//Exibe a Label "Novo" quando a data está no dia atual

    $( ".data" ).each(function() {

      if($(this).html() === output || $(this).html() === ontem){
        $(this).nextAll(".label").css("visibility","visible");    

      }

    });
    
    //Conta quantas Label "Novo" estão visiveis

     $( ".notification-list" ).each(function() {
      if($(".notification-badge > div:visible").length === 0){
        $(".badge").text($(".notification-list div").length)
        
      }

    });

  }, 1000);

};

//Captura de data

d = new Date();

month = d.getMonth()+1;
day = d.getDate();
dayontem = d.getDate() - 1;
output = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();
ontem = (dayontem<10 ? '0' : '') + dayontem + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();


setTimeout(function(){ 

  refreshItens();

  console.log(output);
  console.log(ontem);

}, 1000);
```

```css
.topbar{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:#eee;
  }
.dropbtn {
    
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
  
.badge{
  z-index: 1;
 margin-left:-7px;
 border-radius: .5em;
 font-size: 7pt;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color:#c92121;
 color:#fff;
  }
  
  .notification-badge{
 float: right; 
 margin: 3px;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color:  #32E6C8;
 color:#00285F;
}

.notification-list{
 border-radius: 0px;
 border-left: 0px;
 border-right: 0px;
 cursor: default;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="topbar">
<div class="dropdown">
<div onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x"><span class="badge"></span></i></div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <ul style="width:400px;">
    <li id="painelMsg" style="min-height: 50px; max-height: 400px; overflow: auto;" class="list-group notifica">
      <ul>
<!-- notificação 1 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">08/11/2016</span>  -
   <span class="titulo ">notificação 1</span>
   <div class="label label-primary notification-badge" >NOVO</div> 
</li>
<!-- notificação 2 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">07/11/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 2</span>
   <div class="label label-primary notification-badge" >NOVO</div> 
</li>
<!-- notificação 3 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 3</span>
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
<!-- notificação 4 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 4 </span> 
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
<!-- notificação 5 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 5</span> 
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
<!-- notificação 6 -->
<li  class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 6</span>
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
  
</nav>
  
  
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para exibir o menu dropdown clique abaixo do ícone, nao sei pq no Scackoverflow não está permitindo o clique em cima do icone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já que você faz um loop buscando os label e setando a visibilidade já faz a contagem

```
var count=0;
$( ".data" ).each(function() {
   ...
count++;
```

e no final seto o valor de acordo com o contador.

```
$(".badge").text(cont);
```

Segue o código alterado...

```js
//Função para atualizar as mensagens
function refreshItens(){


  setTimeout(function(){ 

//Exibe a Label "Novo" quando a data está no dia atual

    
    var cont = 0; //criei um contador
    
    $( ".data" ).each(function() {
      if($(this).html() === output || $(this).html() === ontem){
        $(this).nextAll(".label").css("visibility","visible");
        cont++; //quando encontro um label com a data certa incremento o contador

      }

    });
    $(".badge").text(cont); //coloco o valor do contador no lugar dele
    //Conta quantas Label "Novo" estão visiveis
/*
     $( ".notification-list" ).each(function() {
      if($(".notification-badge > div:visible").length === 0){
        
        
      }
    });
*/
  }, 1000);

};

//Captura de data

d = new Date();

month = d.getMonth()+1;
day = d.getDate();
dayontem = d.getDate() - 1;
output = (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();
ontem = (dayontem<10 ? '0' : '') + dayontem + '/' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();


setTimeout(function(){ 

  refreshItens();

  console.log(output);
  console.log(ontem);

}, 1000);
```

```css
.topbar{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  background-color:#eee;
  }
.dropbtn {
    
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}



.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
  
.badge{
  z-index: 1;
 margin-left:-7px;
 border-radius: .5em;
 font-size: 7pt;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color:#c92121;
 color:#fff;
  }
  
  .notification-badge{
 float: right; 
 margin: 3px;
 visibility: hidden;
 background-color:  #32E6C8;
 color:#00285F;
}

.notification-list{
 border-radius: 0px;
 border-left: 0px;
 border-right: 0px;
 cursor: default;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="topbar">
<div class="dropdown">
<div onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-3x"><span class="badge"></span></i></div>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <ul style="width:400px;">
    <li id="painelMsg" style="min-height: 50px; max-height: 400px; overflow: auto;" class="list-group notifica">
      <ul>
<!-- notificação 1 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">10/11/2016</span>  -
   <span class="titulo ">notificação 1</span>
   <div class="label label-primary notification-badge" >NOVO</div> 
</li>
<!-- notificação 2 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">09/11/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 2</span>
   <div class="label label-primary notification-badge" >NOVO</div> 
</li>
<!-- notificação 3 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 3</span>
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
<!-- notificação 4 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 4 </span> 
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
<!-- notificação 5 -->
<li class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 5</span> 
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
<!-- notificação 6 -->
<li  class="list-group-item msg  notification-list"> 
   <span class="data" style="color: #199fae;">20/09/2016</span> - 
   <span class="titulo">notificação 6</span>
   <div class="label notification-badge">NOVO</div>
</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
  
</nav>
  
  
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando insiro div:visible ele indica que tem "0" notificações, quando na verdade existe 1 nova, quando removo conta as 6 notificações.

Comment: Reeditei a resposta dá 1 conferida ?

Comment: Perfeito, valeu brother

Comment: @FelipeScarsSilva se a resposta te ajudou coloque ela como correta ;-)

Comment: Opa ta marcado ja

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso após a execução do `for()`, para os demais elementos, pois você está agregando o 'visible' no elemento com `.css()`:

```
var total = $('.notification-badge[style="visibility: visible;"]').length;
$(".badge").text(total);
```

Porém, como você já está testando uma condição, é uma segunda opção colocar um simples contador:

```
var total = 0;
$( ".data" ).each(function() {
   if ($(this).html() === output || $(this).html() === ontem) {
      $(this).nextAll(".label").css("visibility","visible");
      total++;
   } 
 //...
}
$(".badge").text(total);
```